# Changing the driver link in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am accessing a page behind a log in screen. I have got to the point that I have logged in using the following code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://url')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)


def login_function():
    name_element = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    name_element.send_keys('admin@xyz.com')
    password_element = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_element.send_keys('pass')
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('custom-btn-wrapper')
    login_button.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    new_link = driver.get('https://new_url')
    if new_link == 'new_url':
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')

login_function()
```

So using the above code I log in and at the end of the function I try to get the new page using:

```
new_link = driver.get('https://new_url')
```

where new_url is the url that is supposed to be the correct one after I log in. That is why I have also included .implicitly_wait(5) just to make sure.
However from the if statement I always get No.
I don't understand why I don't get the new url.

Another way I have tried is:

```
driver.current_url()
print(driver)
```

I execute this after I have executer the above mentioned function. Again I can't update the driver to the new url.

Any suggestions to what I am doing wrong and how I can solve this issue.

The end goal is to get the new url link and update the driver OR have a new variable that stores it and from there on to use the new variable.

Comment: ImplicitWait does not wait on get... it's a type of webdriverwait that ignores not found exceptions for a certain amount of time. (it's global so only set it once.)  This has no bearing on .get() method.  What you are doing is changing the current page before your login cookies have written.  You need to either include a sleep here, or check for an update to the DOM that happens only after you are logged in.  (Like welcome, user, you are logged in, or an "account" type link...)

Comment: driver.current_url is being checked before cookies are set and before the re-direct or javascript DOM update.  (whichever the site uses...)  So the flow is: 1)submit login credentials 2) server verifies, and sends back a header that tells the browser to write a cookie... usually a session cookie 3) browser writes cookie to disk and responds to server... with stored cookie (and on all subsequent requests) 4) Server sends a redirect, or a callback to javascript that updates the DOM accordingly....

Answer (score 2):

`driver.get('https://new_url')` doesn't returns anything.

Hence `new_link` will always be *`NULL`* and accordingly you see the **`No`** getting printed.

To print the *current_url* you can use:

```
print(driver.current_url())
```

Comment: Nope this still returns the old url and not the new one. I am not trying to print a url. I am trying to get the url that is used after the log in screen.

Comment: Why not storing the initial url in a variable through `initial_url = driver.current_url()` before `driver.get('https://new_url')`